# Generalisation of posets

Tags: soft-question, category-theory, order-theory

The notion of (set) monoid can be generalised to that of monoid object in a monoidal category. Can the notion of poset be generalised in a similar fashion? How?

Answer (score 3):

The [internalization](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internalization) of preorders are [internal binary relations](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+relation) which are reflexive and transitive.

An internal relation $(d_0,d_1 : R \to X)$ is called *reflexive* if there is a morphism $\Delta : X \to R$ such that $d_0 \Delta = \mathrm{id}_X = d_1 \Delta$. Since $(d_0,d_1)$ are jointly monic, $\Delta$ is unique, if it exists.

An internal relation $(d_0,d_1 : R \to X)$ is called *transitive* if for all morphisms $u : T \to R$, $v : T \to R$ with $d_1 u = d_0 v$ there is some morphism $w : T \to R$ with $d_0 w = d_0 u$ and $d_1 w = d_1 v$. Again, $w$ is unique, if it exists.

This describes internal preorders. We get internal posets by adding antisymmetry:

An internal relation $(d_0,d_1 : R \to X)$ is called *antisymmetric* if for all morphisms $u : T \to R$, $v : T \to R$ with $d_1 u = d_0 v$ and $d_0 u = d_1 v$ we have $d_0 u = d_1 u$.

Comment: It seems like this notion could  be used to define an "ordered monoid" in a monoidal category, although I am not sure this would be a "good" definition.

Comment: Beware that if your category is not [regular](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/regular+category), then composition of binary relations is not associative. I haven't looked at this carefully, but I suspect this will mean that in a non-regular category, internal posets may fail to satisfy "higher transitivity" conditions (e.g. the condition that $wRx \wedge xRy \wedge yR z \implies w R z$). Also note that internal posets in the category of groups are not the same as ordered groups, because in an ordered group the inversion operation is order-reversing rather than order-preserving.